# Testing index view sort order in RSpec feature spec (Capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

An index view of a Rails 4.2 app has a table with sort links at its header. If the user clicks the "E-mail" header, records are sorted by E-mail, and so on. When a sort link is clicked, the page is reloaded (with a query string like `q=email+asc`). AJAX is not yet used.

I've written the following test. It works, but I believe there should be a better way to test this.

```
it "sorts by e-mail when the 'E-mail' column header is clicked", :focus do
  visit "/admin/users"
  expected_id_order = User.order(:email).map(&:id)
  # Once the page is reloaded (the new sort order is applied), the "stale"
  # class will disappear. Note that due to Turbolinks, only the part of
  # the DOM that is modified by a request will have its elements replaced.
  page.execute_script("$('tr.user:first').addClass('stale')")
  within "thead" do
    click_link("E-mail")
  end
  # Force Capybara to wait until the page is reloaded
  expect(page).to have_no_selector("tr.user.stale")
  actual_id_order = page.body.scan(/<tr.+id="user_(.+)".*>/).flatten
  expect(actual_id_order).to eq(expected_id_order)
end
```

Additional details:

- `<TR>` elements have DOM IDs containing the DB IDs of their corresponding records, like `<tr class="user" id="user_34">`. Using regex to extract the order in which the records are displayed in the page is probably not the best solution. Can you suggest a better way?
- I don't like the JavaScript hack (using JQuery to add the `stale` class and then waiting until it disappears to ensure the page was reloaded), but so far I could not find another way to ensure Capybara waits until the page is reloaded (the new sort order is applied). Can you suggest a better way?
- The application uses Devise, so we need to create a user record in order to login. Note that the user created for login purposes inevitably appears in our test data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to use the fact that you control the test data, assign the strings accordingly and then use a regex to test the output a user would actually see rather than specific tags and ids.

```
within_table('user_table') do # any method that will scope to the table
  expect(page).to have_text /user3@test\.com.+user2@test\.com.+user1@test\.com/ # initial expected ordering
  click_link("E-mail")
  expect(page).to have_text /user1@test\.com.+user2@test\.com.+user3@test\.com/ # sorted expected ordering
end
```

Capybara will wait, no JS hack needed, etc.

Comment: I did not expect an answer from Capybara's top contributor, thank you. That is delightfully simple and readable. What is your approach to creating the test data? If a page can be filtered by 8 different attributes, do we need to create 3 records and set their attribute's values "manually" within the test (3*8 = 24 attribute values) or is there a simpler way to do it with `FactoryGirl.create_list`?

Comment: @BrunoFacca You're using FactoryGirl so rather than using create_list just create the 3 records you need specifying just the field that needs to be a specific value (email for this case) for each test.   `create(:user, email: 'email3@test.com';  create(:user, email: 'email2@test.com'); ...` etc.  They will be created in ascending id order, then assuming they are initially displayed in ascending id order you know how they should start, and how they should end.  Note you could also do the creation with an array `%w(email3@...).each { |email| create(:user email: email) }`

Comment: Thanks again. I've forgot to mention something (sorry, I've just edited the question): The application uses Devise, so we need to create a user record in order to login. That user created for login purposes inevitably "pollutes" our test data.

Comment: @BrunoFacca Either create the login user with known values that work with your sorting, or don't worry about it since when verifying sorting with a regex it would just get ignored as part of the `.+` between the other values wherever it sorts to.

Comment: Haven't thought about how it would get ignored as part of `.+`. Thank you!

Comment: I've posted the entire feature spec (including other tests) [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171152/rails-crud-feature-specs-rspec-and-capybara). If you eventually have the time to take a quick look, I'd be very grateful. Unfortunately, the Code Review forum does not have a "Capybara" tag and I don't have enough reputation to create it.

Answer (score 1):

Taking ideas from [this blog post](http://launchware.com/articles/acceptance-testing-asserting-sort-order) you could do something like

```
# get the index of the first occurrence of each users' email address in the response body
actual_order = User.order(:email).map { |user| page.body.index(user.email) }
# should already be in sorted order
expect(actual_order).to eq(actual_order.sort)
```

As for having to wait for the `.stale` class to be removed, I'd suggest instead modifying your html to include some sort of "this is the currently sorted column" class on your `th` or `a` tags.

```
<a id="email-sort-link" class="sorted asc">E-Mail</a>
```

and then you could wait until you see `a#email-sort-link.sorted`. Don't usually like modifying code to facilitate testing, but this seems minor enough and allows you to style the link differently to remind the user the current sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a specific case where I wanted to use shared examples. So I have created the following based on Thomas Walpole's answer.

```
def sort_order_regex(*sort_by_attributes)
  /#{User.order(sort_by_attributes)
         .map { |u| Regexp.quote(u.email) }
         .join(".+")}/
end

RSpec.shared_examples "sort link" do |link_text:, sort_by:|
  # Make sure your factory creates unique values for all sortable attributes
  before(:each) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 3) }

  it "sorts by #{sort_by} when the #{link_text} link is clicked" do
    visit "/admin/users"
    # Check the record's order by matching the order of their e-mails (unique).
    initial_order = sort_order_regex(:first_name, :last_name)
    tested_order = sort_order_regex(sort_by)
    within_table "users_table" do
      expect(page).to have_text(initial_order)
      click_link(link_text, exact: false)
      expect(page).to have_text(tested_order)
    end
  end
end

describe "User CRUD", type: :feature, js: true do
  describe "sorting" do
    include_examples "sort link", link_text: "E-mail", sort_by: :email
    include_examples "sort link", link_text: "Role", sort_by: :role
    include_examples "sort link", link_text: "Country", sort_by: :country
    include_examples "sort link", link_text: "Quotes", sort_by: :quotes_count
  end
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

We can test it with CSS stuff.

An example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     username        |     email        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     bot1            | bot1@mail.com    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     bot2            | bot2@mail.com    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Our RSpec can be like:

```rb
RSpec.describe "returns expected sorted row data" do
  it 'returns expected sorted row data' do
    # the headers column name
    within 'tr:nth-child(1)' do
      expect(page).to have_text 'username password'
    end

    # the second row
    within 'tr:nth-child(2)' do
      expect(page).to have_text 'bot1 bot1@mail.com'
    end

    # the third row
    within 'tr:nth-child(3)' do
      expect(page).to have_text 'bot2 bot2@mail.com'
    end
  end
end
```